# VIM: delete strings with the same pattern

Tags: vim

I need to find all pairs of strings that have the same pattern.
For example:

```
another string, that is not interesting
la-di-da-di __pattern__ -di-la-di-la
la-di-da-da-di-la __pattern__ -la-da-li-la
and yet another usual string
```

So I want to delete strings with __pattern__ inside.

I don't know how to do it just with builtin commands and now I have the function, that doesn't work properly:

```
function! DelDup(pattern)
    echom a:pattern
    redir => l:count
    execute "normal! :%s/a:pattern//n\<cr>"
    redir END
    echo l:count
endfunction
```

Here I try to run ":%s/a:pattern//n" to find the count of occurrences of pattern in the text.
And at the same time I try to put it into the variable "l:count".
Then I tried to echo the count I got, but nothing happens when I try to do it.

So the last my problem in function writing is that I can't write the command execution result to variable.

If you have another solution -- please describe it to me.

**Update:**
Excuse me for bad description. I want to delete only strings, that has pattern-twins in text.

Comment: Do you want to delete ? Or do you want to count the number of times your pattern is matched in your buffer?

Comment: @LucHermitte I want to delete each occurrence if count is bigger than 2. The part of function is just my attempts to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I'm assuming you want to remove all lines where there are at least 2 matches. If that's the case you can use the following command:

```
:g/\(__pattern__.*\)\{2,}/d
```

How this works is that it deletes all the lines where there is a match (`:g/../d`).
The pattern is made up of a group (`\(..\)`) which needs to be matched at least 2 times (`\{2,}`). And the pattern has a `.*` at the end so it matches everything between the matches of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to count occurrences of a pattern, and I'm quite sure there exist a Q/A on the subject. Let's do it yet another way and chain with the next step. (Yes this is completely obfuscated, but it permits to obtain programmatically the information without the need to parse the localized result of `:substitute` after redirection.)

```
" declare a list that contain all matches
let matches = []

" replace each occurrence of the "pattern" with:
" the result of the expression "\=" that can be 
" interpreted as the last ([-1]) element of the 
" list "matches" returned by the function (add) 
" that adds the current match (submatch(0)) to the
" list
:%s/thepattern/\=add(matches, submatch(0))[-1]/gn
" The big caveat of this command is that it modifies 
" the current buffer.
" We need something like the following to leave it unmodified:
:g/thepattern/call substitute(getline('.'), 'thepattern', '\=add(counter, submatch(0))[-1]', 'g')
" Note however that this flavour won't work with multi-lines patterns

" Now you can test the number of matches or do anything fancy with it
if len(matches) > 1
  " replaces matches with nothing
  :%s/thepattern//g
endif
```

Only if you want to define this as a function you'll need to play with:

```
exe 'normal :%s/'.escape(a:pattern, '/\').'/replacement..../flags....'
```